# How to concatenate a string with a variable to the new variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script like this,

```
#!/bin/bash
foxy1="foxyserver"
H="1"
```

and the output should be *foxyserver*.

I tried this,

```
echo $foxy$H
```

and this gives me

```
1
```

and then I used

```
str="foxy$H"
echo $str
```

the output is

```
foxy1
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [indirect variables, as described in BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006):

```
$ foxy1="foxyserver"
$ H="1"
$ varname="foxy$H"
$ echo "${!varname}"
foxyserver
```

Answer (score 2):

Using eval, you can do indirection:

```
eval echo \$$str
```

*Output*

```
foxyserver
```

*Warning*: This is not really good practice. For example, if you have `str=(rm -rf ~/*)` then the eval expression would be `$(rm -rf ~/*)`. So be warned and use indirection as suggested by Charles Duffy.

Comment: From a security perspective, this is bad practice. Indirect variables would _only_ let you name a variable to be expanded, whereas eval lets your variables' contents do literally anything.